# Tiff image pixel values reading using java

Tags: java, tiff, geotiff

Respected sir/madam,
As i am new to tiff image handling with java,i want to compare two tiff images based on their pixel values.I started reading tiff image header such as image width,rows per strip etc. using imageio.(http://dipakpardesi.blogspot.in/).
But i am not getting how to read pixel values,please suggest me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: i read tiff image header values using their tag nos.such as width,height,bits per sample,pixel size,xResolution,yResolution etc.But i dont know how to read pixel values.Please suggest me to resolve this.